# JavaFX fx:id NullPointerException

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Если я создаю объекты javaFX сам, в коде java и вызываю их методы, проблем нету. Если я в fxml определяю элементы управления и по действию с ними, в методы класса контроллера отправляю, тоже проблем нет. Все работает по аннотациям. Но если мне надо из определенной, например, кнопки в fxml по клику вызвать обработку действия в коде java (кнопка имеет fx:id и определена в контроллере), то я получаю NullPointerException. И я никак не могу понять, почему. Не могу же я определить кнопку в fxml и потом назначить ей новый объект в коде, тогда зачем мне fxml? Найти в интернете решение мне не удается, везде написано "используйте fx:id и будет вам счастье, программу надо писать с использованием fxml", но я не понимаю, как его с кодом связывать. Они вместе не хотят работать, как мне надо. Запускать методы в контроллере написанные, из fxlm элементов можно. Но мне не подходит обработка методами, мне нужно чтобы определенный элемент я мог по его fx:id вызвать. Например, кнопка **addButton**, я получаю NullPointerException еще на моменте запуска приложения (25 строка `noteList.getChildren().add((button));`).
Аналогично я не могу методы на кнопках использовать, к примеру `addButton.setOnAction`

Controller:

```
public class Wtf extends Application {

   @FXML
    AnchorPane noteList;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("wtf.fxml"));
        final Parent root = loader.load();
        Button button = new Button();
        noteList.getChildren().add((button));


        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<Pane fx:controller="Wtf" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="noteList" layoutX="119.0" layoutY="68.0" prefHeight="292.0" prefWidth="288.0">
         <children>
            <VBox layoutX="44.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="207.0" prefWidth="190.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

StackTrace:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tests.Wtf.start(Wtf.java:25)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$3(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом экземпляре Wtf вызывается метод start, далее строчкой `final Parent root = loader.load();` создается второй экземпляр Wtf, где `noteList` инициализируется аннотацией. Дальше по коду мы возвращаемся к первому экземпляру Wtf, где noteList не инициализирован и вызвать у null какой-либо метод еще ни у кого не получилось. Сделать один и тот же класс входом в программу и назначить контроллером плохое решение.